# Frog CMS htaccess diagnosis

Tags: .htaccess

I have a issue with Frog CMS, its the first time I use this CMS, is a client that uses this.

Scenario: I modified 1 redirection using a plugin called "Redirector" that destroyed the whole site!

Luckly, I found an htaccess from some months ago, that allows the site to work, but the redirections none of them works, the site works, but not the redirections, the main url rewriting for the site seems to be Ok, but the 301 redirects I need, dont work.

I cant figure out why this is happening, why this redirections dont work correctly, they dont conflict, but they dont do nothing! Can you advice on this ? Im looking forward uderstanding more about url rewritting and htaccess.

I cant use the plugin to generate redirections, because it destroyed the whole site. If there is a way to "reset" the url rewritting in this CMS it would be good, but I dont have cooperation form the developers of the site...

I appreciate any help to understand better what is wrong , why all the

```
 RewriteRule ^site/services/immigration/ /services/immigration.html [L,R=301]
```

dont work!

```
### CMS-Generated Update August 1, 2013, 1:45 pm ###

#
# Setting Frog requirements
#
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType video/ogg .ogm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/x-m4v .m4v
AddType audio/webm .weba
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.local$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.local$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^install/index.html$ install/index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^install/index.php$ install/index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^install/$ install/index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ admin/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^$ /cache/index.html [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cache/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ /downloads.php?THISPAGE=download.html&media=pdf&filename=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^private/(.*)$ /private.html?THISPAGE=private.html&userfile=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^mobile/search/(.*)$ mobile.html?THISPAGE=search.html&media=mobile&search=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)/process.html$ mobile.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=mobile&return=process [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)/success.html$ mobile.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=mobile&return=success [L,QSA]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^standard/search/(.*)$ standard.html?THISPAGE=search.html&media=standard&search=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#RewriteRule ^standard/(.*)/process.html$ standard.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=standard&return=process [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^standard/(.*)/success.html$ standard.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=standard&return=success [L,QSA]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/process.html$ contact.html?THISPAGE=$1&return=process [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)/success.html$ contact.html?THISPAGE=$1&return=success [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ index.php?THISPAGE=search.html&search=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^proposal.html$ index.php?THISPAGE=$1&media=proposal [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^contrast/search/(.*)$ contrast.html?THISPAGE=search.html&search=$1&media=contrast [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^print/search/(.*)$ print.html?THISPAGE=search.html&search=$1&media=print [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)$ mobile.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=mobile [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^standard/(.*)$ standard.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=standard [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^print/(.*)$ print.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=print [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^pdf/(.*)$ pdf.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=pdf [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^proposal/(.*)$ proposal.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=proposal [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^flash/(.*)$ flash.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=flash [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^contrast/(.*)$ contrast.html?THISPAGE=$1&media=contrast [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?THISPAGE=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/site/aboutus/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/aboutus/ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^pages/about_us.htm /about.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/contact/ /contact.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/library/ /resources.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/ /services.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/alternative_dispute_resolution/ /services/alternative-dispute-resolution.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/business_visas/ /services/business-visas.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/civil_comm_litigation/ /services/civil-commercial-litigation-copy.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/clinical_negligence/ /services/clinical-negligence.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/conveyancing/commercial/ /services/commercial-conveyancing.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/company_law/ /services/company-law.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/criminal_law/ /services/criminal-law.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/divorce_matrimonial/ /services/divorce-matrimonial.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/employment_law/ /services/employment-law.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/human_rights/ /services/human-rights-issues.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/immigration/ /services/immigration.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/leases_tenancy/ /services/leases-tenancy-agreements.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/injury_medical_negligence/ /services/personal-injury-medical-negligence.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/pro_bono/ /services/pro-bono.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/conveyancing/ /services/residential-conveyancing.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/conveyancing/residential/ /services/residential-conveyancing.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/services/wills_trusts_probates/ /services/wills-trusts-probates.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^site/people/ /team.html [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have this rule *before* all of your other services redirect rules:

```
RewriteRule ^site/services/ /services.html [L,R=301]
```

This is saying, "anything that **starts with** `/site/services/` gets redirected to `/services.html`". So, when you have a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^site/services/company_law/ /services/company-law.html [L,R=301]
```

after it, the second rule **will never get executed**, since the second rule matches `/site/services/company_law`, *which starts with* `/site/services/`, thus matching the first rule. You need to re-order all of your rules so that the more general rule is at the end. Just put the

```
RewriteRule ^site/services/ /services.html [L,R=301]
```

rule at the very bottom.

Comment: thanks for your help jon, this was good for me to understand. but for some reason, no redirects are working. all of them give 404 error when I try to open in the browser.

Comment: @glowzar do you have mod_rewrite loaded?